# how to set a default value in a filter in the cognos 11 dashboard when opening the dashboard?

Tags: dashboard, cognos-11

I have a dashboard in cognos 11.1.7 and I need that when the user opens the dashboard it shows the data of the current month and the user can change the month.

Comment: What did you tried so far ? What is not working ?

Comment: You will need to state what you are using in the dashboard.  If you are using a module then you can set up relative time measures in it and use the _as_of_date parameter, which the user can change.  You could also have a filter expression where you use the last value for month, provided it is sorted.  Dashboards allow you change filters.  If you are using a dynamic cube or another cube, they usually have relative time measures built in.  If you are using a FM package you could do something similar to the module approach (although it does not support relative time measures).

Comment: It also depends on what is meant by 'current month'.  A current month could be the actual month in which the dashboard is run.  For example today is January 29, which would make the current month in that sense January.  Or the current month could be the last complete month, which you see a lot of in financial and managerial reports.  In that case, it would be December of 2020.  Another thing to consider is what you want or what exactly is needed for prompting to change the filter and how you want to set the default value.  You could want to look at macros (if you are using FM)

Comment: Does this have to be a dashboard?  Or can it be a report that is designed to look like a dashboard?